# Assuming that the given sequence converges, find its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I've been working on this for a while, using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_hUHytoYxs) as a reference, but cannot seem to figure this out. It is a not-for-marks calculus 2 question. The given answer is H.

[image]

Could somebody give me simple steps to the given solution? Thanks!

Comment: Solve $a=2+\frac  1  a$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I only get a = 1 or 3, which neither is the given answer.

Comment: $a^{2}-2a-1=0$,. This gives $a=1\pm \sqrt 2$. Use  the fact that $a_n>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that as $n\to \infty$ we have a repeating fraction given by
$$a_\infty = 2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\cdots}}.$$
Thus, to find $a_\infty$ it suffices to solve $a_\infty = 2+\frac{1}{a_\infty}$ which yields solutions $a_\infty = 1+\sqrt{2}$ or $a_\infty=1-\sqrt{2}$. Clearly $a_\infty$ is positive since we are continually adding positive numbers. So the answer will be (H)!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But how do you solve for $a$? I think I'm doing something silly, but I get it to the point of $a(a-2) = 1$, so $a = 1 or 3$.

Comment: Hello! Yes, you solve for $a_\infty$ which will be the roots of the quadratic $a_\infty = 2+ \frac{1}{a_\infty}\implies a_\infty^2-2 a_\infty - 1 = 0$

Comment: @MATHBOI Just take limits in the given equation to get $a=2+\frac  1 a$. You are making things too complicated.

Comment: @MATHBOI and geetha290krm Got it! It clicked, thanks both of you!